# Remove unused through Regular Expression javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an Html code editor which contains the following options in it.

1. Remove class,
2. Remove comments

I found it i can remove them using Regular Expression like this,..

```
input_htmlcode.replace(/(?!<\")\/\*[^\*]+\*\/(?!\")/g,'')
```

Please help me to write regEx.

Answer (score 2):

For your **class** I would go with the following regex:

```
(\sclass=(["'])[\w\s-_]+(?2))
```

this will catch everything:

- that starts with a whitespace `\s`
- has the exact phrase "class=" `class=`
- followed by a single our double quote (that we capture for the closing match) `(["'])`
- followed by at least one or more letter, whitespace, dash or underscore `[\w\s-_]+`
- followed by the same brace that was used to open `(?2)`

For your **html comment** I would go with something like this:

```
(<!--[^(-->)]*-->)
```

this will catch:

- that starts with `<!--`
- followed by any number of characters that do not match --> `[^(-->)]*`
- followed by `-->`

Comment: Removing Class script is not working. it contains errors though. Can you help me to fix it.

Comment: It worked for me on regex101.com... If you could be a bit more specific about the error I'll see what I clan do...

Comment: if it is like this, it removes till the next set of double quotes in the line. <div class="test" id="sample" > . The regEx will remove til the id.

Answer (score 1):

```
()  means a section of the expression
?   the content before question mark is optional
.   dot means any character
+   any number of the expression before this
g   global search
```

You can test it or make your own on this page:
https://regex101.com/

For class:

```
/class(="(.+)?")?/g
```

For comment:

```
/<!--.+-->/g
```